# How to apply style on child tag of child tag?

Tags: css, sass

```
<div class="product">
 <div class="image">
   <div class="mainimage"></div>
   <div class="secondimage"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="productdescription"></div>
</div>
```

At the mouse hover on class `productdescription` I want to apply **display: block** on class `secondimage`. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't do it without javascript, because the trigger element .productdescription have to be a parent of the element .secondimage.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this in pure CSS with the structure you have, as a general rule CSS avoids any selectors that 'travel up' the DOM node tree to avoid complexity. However if you swap the order like so:

```
<div class="product">
 <div class="productdescription"></div>
 <div class="image">
   <div class="mainimage"></div>
   <div class="secondimage"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then you should be able to do the following using the [Adjacent Sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```
.productdescription:hover + .image .secondimage{
    display:block;
}
```

```css
.productdescription:hover + .image .secondimage{
    display:block;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
 <div class="productdescription">Product Description</div>
 <div class="image">
   <div class="mainimage">Main Image</div>
   <div class="secondimage">Second Image</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you need to keep the structure, then a bit of JavaScript/jQuery is required.

```js
$(".productdescription").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".image .secondimage").toggleClass("hoverActive")
});
```

```css
.secondimage.hoverActive{
    display:block;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
 <div class="image">
   <div class="mainimage">Main Image</div>
   <div class="secondimage">Second Image</div>
 </div>
  <div class="productdescription">Product Description</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need some JavaScript and jQuery to do this.

After putting an id in each div you want to interact:

```
$('#productDescription').hover(function(){
    $('#secondImage').css("display","block");
});
```

I don't know if it's what you looking for, but it works.